# Access Paperclip image before it's uploaded to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

My Rails app uploads images to S3 with Paperclip. I want to "intercept" the image before it is sent to S3, convert it to base64, and send it to a third-party API.

How can I access the image before it gets uploaded by Paperclip to S3? This would be quicker than reading the file from S3 afterwards, and then sending it to the third-party API.

Comment: Hey, how did you end up performing the actual conversion after using Roman's answer to access the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image

  before_save :send_image

  private

  def send_image
    image.queued_for_write[:original] # <= this is your image
  end
end
```

Comment: Any idea how to convert this file to PDF using Prawn before it gets written to S3 by Paperclip?