# Convert images to PDF before uploading with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-s3, paperclip, prawn

Using Paperclip for file upload in my Rails app and I need to convert images into separate PDFs before uploading to Amazon S3 servers. I know I can use Prawn for the image to PDF conversion and I can intercept the file using the answer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344301/access-paperclip-image-before-its-uploaded-to-s3)

In the model:

```
has_attached_file :file
before_file_post_process :convert_images
```

...

```
def convert_images
    if file_content_type == 'image/png' || file_content_type == 'image/jpeg'
        original_file = file.queued_for_write[:original]
        filename = original_file.path.to_s
        pdf = Prawn::Document.new
        pdf.image open(filename), :scale => 1.0, position: :center
        file = pdf.render
    end
end
```

However I'm unable to actually convert the image that is stored on S3. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Edit: Adding a `save!` call results in validations failing that weren't doing so before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out.

changed:

```
before_file_post_process :convert_images
```

to:

```
before_save :convert_images
```

and changed my `convert_images` method to:

```
def convert_images
  if file_content_type == 'image/png' || file_content_type == 'image/jpeg'
    file_path = file.queued_for_write[:original].path.to_s
    temp_file_name = file_file_name.split('.')[0] + '.pdf'
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "LETTER", :page_layout => :portrait)
    pdf.image File.open("#{file_path}"), :fit => [612, 792], position: :center
    pdf.render_file temp_file_name
    file_content_type = 'application/pdf'
    self.file = File.open(temp_file_name)
    File.delete(temp_file_name)
  end
end
```